# Reset alarm with Alarm Manager after force stop the application

Tags: android, service, notifications, alarmmanager, forceclose

I followed this post http://it-ride.blogspot.com/2010/10/android-implementing-notification.html to implement a Notification Service. It uses AlarmManager and Wakelock to start a service. When you restart the device the alarm is set correctly or when you open the app the alarm is set, but if you force close the app the alarm is gone. I would like to reset the alarm after the app is forced stopped. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

According to Google's Android engineers, an app that is forcefully stopped will not start again until the user invokes it.

Check out the following response found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/Zi0Qq2G2ikg).